# SharePoint formula Question

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation

Is it possible to control via "Sharepoint formula" to validate a DateTime field to accept only a value between the current date and 4 months later?

For example: 15 June 2015 to 15 Oct 2017, always validating that the date is between the current and 4 months later.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=and([date1]>today(),[date1]<(today()+120))
```

Replace **today()** by **[created]** if you need to use this colummn.

Image  [here](http://surpoint.blogspot.com.ar/2017/06/validar-que-un-campo-fecha-se-encuentre.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've noticed that I can use the "Created" field like "Today"
but...
Is it possible to calculate the difference of months between the "Created" field and another DateTime field and that only allows the rank of 4 months from the date created?

Comment: I totally updated my answer because I had misunderstood. Apologies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, don't Worry.  I have put the formula: "=and([Validity]>[Created],[Validity]<([Created]+120))" (without quotation mark), But SharePoint send me sintax error: "Lo sentimos, se ha producido un problema" "La fórmula contiene un error de sintaxis o no se admite.". I have reviewed, but the formula looks good. Help!

Comment: It is spanish? Change "," by ";"